# Add vertex gives a "Undefined column name" error while schema is correct

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I'm running into a blocking issue.

In my DSE studio i started to modify my schema :

```
schema.propertyKey("longitude").Double().single().ifNotExists().create()
schema.propertyKey("latitude").Double().single().ifNotExists().create()
schema.vertexLabel("Locality").properties('longitude','latitude').add()
```

Then I check it using `schema.vertexLabel("Locality").describe()` :

> schema.vertexLabel("Locality").properties([...], "longitude",
>   "latitude").create()

So that's OK.

But when I try to add a vertex :

`g.addV(label, 'Locality', [...], 'longitude', 47.3510905, 'latitude', 0.6622524)`

I get the following error :

> org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException:
>   Undefined column name latitude

I suspect the Cassandra structure not to be synced with the graph schema.

Do you have a solution to solve this issue ?

Precision: I'm using DSE 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to incorrect syntax when using `g.addV()`. You are using the syntax for `graph.addVertex()`. In the case of `g.addV()` your call should look like this:

```
g.addV('Locality').property([...]).property('longitude', 47.3510905).property('latitude', 0.6622524)
```

Note the use of multiple `property()` steps, one for each property set.

For documentation, see the DSE 5.1 docs here:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/insertDataGremlin.html?hl=addv

Comment: I'd like to check that Cassandra structure is fine. But I can't find any documentation about it... Do you for example how to check that a column "latitude" related to a table "Locality" exists in cassandra using cql command ?